# Como obter somente strings que contenham a palavra "x"

Tags: php, php-domdocument

Eu estou pegando através de um parser com DOM PHP todos os links de uma página.
Eu eu preciso pegar apenas os links que contenha a palavra "comprar-toyota"

Eu estava utilizando o seguinte código, mas de uma hora pra outra parou de funcionar:

```
//array que pega o valor do parser
$toyota =array();

$dom1 = new DOMDocument();
$dom1->loadHTMLFile('http://www.webmotors.com.br/comprar/carros/novos-usados/sp-sao-paulo/toyota/?tipoveiculo=carros&anunciante=pessoa%20f%C3%ADsica&tipoanuncio=novos%7Cusados&estado1=s%C3%A3o%20paulo&marca1=toyota&anode=2012&anoate=&kmde=&kmate=30000&p=1&o=1&qt=36');

// Consultando os links
$links1 = $dom1->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links1 as $link) {

   //aqui pega o link
   $string = $link->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;

            //apenas verifica se o link nao tem a string "comprar/toyota"
            if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') != 1){
                //nadafaz;
            }else{
                //verifica se o link tem a string "comprar/toyota"
                if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') == 1){ 
                    //guarda a string encontrada
                    $linky = $string;

                    $n++;

                    #echo $n."<br>";

                    //insere o link no array
                    $toyota[$n] = $linky;

                    //imprime oo link
                    echo $toyota[$n]."<br>";
                }                   
    }
}
```

Então inverti a condição do strpos em meu if ficando assim:

```
//array que pega o valor do parser
$toyota =array();

$dom1 = new DOMDocument();
$dom1->loadHTMLFile('http://www.webmotors.com.br/comprar/carros/novos-usados/sp-sao-paulo/toyota/?tipoveiculo=carros&anunciante=pessoa%20f%C3%ADsica&tipoanuncio=novos%7Cusados&estado1=s%C3%A3o%20paulo&marca1=toyota&anode=2012&anoate=&kmde=&kmate=30000&p=1&o=1&qt=36');

// Consultando os links
$links1 = $dom1->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links1 as $link) {

   //aqui pega o link
   $string = $link->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;

            //apenas verifica se o link nao tem a string "comprar/toyota"
            if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') == 1){
                //nadafaz;
            }else{
                //verifica se o link tem a string "comprar/toyota"
                if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') != 1){ 
                    //guarda a string encontrada
                    $linky = $string;

                    $n++;

                    #echo $n."<br>";

                    //insere o link no array
                    $toyota[$n] = $linky;

                    //imprime oo link
                    echo $toyota[$n]."<br>";
                }                   
    }
}
```

Agora está puxando todos os links da página...eu precisava pegar somente os que tem a string "comprar-toyota" em qualquer parte do link

Como posso fazer para arrumar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua

```
//apenas verifica se o link nao tem a string "comprar/toyota"
if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') == 1){
    //nadafaz;
}else{
            //verifica se o link tem a string "comprar/toyota"
            if(strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') != 1){ 
                //guarda a string encontrada
                $linky = $string;

                $n++;

                #echo $n."<br>";

                //insere o link no array
                $toyota[$n] = $linky;

                //imprime oo link
                echo $toyota[$n]."<br>";
            }                   
}
```

POR

```
// apenas verifica se o link nao tem a string "comprar/toyota" 
if (strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') !== false) {
    //guarda a string encontrada
    $linky = $string;
    $n++;
    #echo $n."<br>";

    //insere o link no array
    $toyota[$n] = $linky;

    //imprime oo link
    echo $toyota[$n]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado fera! Foi certeiro...

Comment: Contempla o desejado pelo AP, mas não esta 100% correto.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, voce tinha razão. O pior que eu tinha usado comparação de tipo no teste que fiz, porém quando postei a resposta usei > 0 .

Answer (score 1):

Como diz no manual  sobre `strpos`:

> Retorna a posição numérica da primeira ocorrência de needle dentro de haystack.
>   Se needle não for encontrado, strpos() irá retornar o boolean FALSE.

Se você esta apenas verificando se sua `string` possui uma determinada `string` deve se usar `strpos($minhaStr, $checkStr) !== false`, pois a string pode existir na na primeiro posição `0`, assim não retornaria o desejado em :

```
if(strpos($minhaStr, $checkStr))   // se a string existir em 0 não entrara no if, pois 0 é considerado false.
if(strpos($minhaStr, $checkStr) > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apenas um detalhe para ficar 100%,  a sua condição deve ser modificada para:

```
if (strpos($string, 'comprar-toyota'))
```

e não:

```
if (strpos($string, 'comprar/toyota') > 0)
```

O problema esta exatamente  no retorno da função como especificado na documentação do php:

> Se needle não for encontrado, strpos() irá retornar o boolean FALSE.

Exemplo 1:

```
$string = 'www.loja.com.br/comprar-toyota';

 if (strpos($string, 'comprar-toyota') > 0) {
      // funcionará.
}
```

Exemplo 2:

```
$string = 'comprar-toyota';

 if (strpos($string, 'comprar-toyota') > 0) {
      // não funcionará.
}
```